# JS Compare array with itself except for the same object

Tags: javascript

How do i compare an array with itself but not for the same object

```
var i = 0;
var boo = true;
while (i < this.bombs.length) {
    if (this.bombs[i] === this.bombs[i]) {
        console.log("true");
        boo = true;
    } else {
        boo = false;
    }
    i++;
    return boo;
}
```

But it should not check `bombs[i]` with `bombs[i]`

Comment: I don't get what you are asking.

Comment: Under what circumstances would `this.bombs[i] === this.bombs[i]` be false?

Comment: `this.bombs[i] === this.bombs[i]` <- this doesn't make sense. Of course they're the same you're looking for the same information at the same time. There is no variation between them at all. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: never because that is the problem that statement is wrong thats what im asking it should check the whole array except the same i in the array

Comment: you need two nested loops

Comment: well it is simple.... you will reset true to false if the next one is not.... and you need to return outside. The way it is currenly written, it will never loop.

Comment: and why are you using `while` for the semantics of `for`?

Comment: `for` loop inside a `for` loop, skipping when `i === j`.

Comment: @Nope Can you show me an example please?

Comment: @Midorikawa it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to check if the array contains duplicates?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The array contains objects with 2 coordinates x and y but one object can't have the same coordinates as another object

Comment: then it gets a bit more complicated, as you can't compare objects by their content with `===`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca so is it even possible what i want?

Comment: @Midorikawa give us a sample array and I'll make an example

Comment: Array has 8 objects

1: {x: 2,  y: 3}
2: {x: 4,  y: 6}

etc.

But X and Y are randomly generated

Answer (score 1):

You need two nested loops, and skip when they point to the same object. Here's a naive implementation

```
let bombs = [{x: 1, y:2}, {x: 1, y: 4}, {x: 1, y: 2}];
let boo = false;

for (let i = 0; i < bombs.length && !boo; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < bombs.length; j++) {
        if (i === j) continue; // this is where you don't compare the object with itself
        if (bombs[i].x === bombs[j].x && bombs[i].y === bombs[j].y) {
            boo = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```